# Why top right corner has red in Android emulator?

Tags: react-native, android-emulator

I am running my react native app on Android emulator. I saw the red background on top right corner. Is it normal? I haven't tried on a physical device yet. Also, my iOS simulator doesn't have this issue. Can someone tell me know to avoid it? Thanks!!!

[image]

Comment: It is there even I set the app in the background...

Answer (score 0):

It may be a case of any background app running , please try giving a color to StatusBar rather than default so it overrides the color. 
YOu can import like this in your component:

```
<StatusBar backgroundColor="blue" barStyle="light-content" />
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: It just have one single app running, there is no other app sitting in background. But thanks though.